# Spotify API 1.0 -- no addEventListener method exposed for player object

Tags: spotify

The Spotify API docs suggest that the player class exposes an addEventListener method:

```
models.player.addEventListener('change', function() { … });
```

I am getting undefined when trying to reference this method:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require("$api/models");
console.log(models.player);
console.log(models.player.addEventListener);
```

The second log message returns 'undefined'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a Javascript noob, but I have successfully connected to addEventListener using the recommended format for require.  I don't think you're supposed to call getSpotifyApi any more.

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
 ...
});
```

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/upgrade-guide/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The code you are writing uses the API 0.x, that is why `models.player.addEventListener` is not defined. You need to use the more recent version of the API, 1.x.

If you want to detect a change in the `Player` you need to do:

```js
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
  models.player.addEventListener('change', function(p) {
    // p.data.track contains the current track
  });
});
```

You have an example of that in the ["Current track" example in the Apps Tutorial](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/playing/current-track.html).